# Search button not working flash builder mobile

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, search, flash-builder

am trying to develope a dictionary program for mobile phone ( android) using Flash builder 4.6

the problem is the Search button isnt working i have tried different codes but without any success , also am pretty  new to flash programming

note that this xml file is longer but i had to reduce it to make it better for reading

this is my xml file:

---

```
<list>
    <Dictionary>
              <id>1</id>
              <term>ok</term>
              <defin>Advanced Audio Coding</defin>
</Dictionary>
<Dictionary>
<id>6</id>
<term>absolute address</term>
<defin>a fixed location in the computer's memory.</defin>
</Dictionary>
<Dictionary>
<id>7</id>
<term>absolute URL</term>
<defin>a URL that contains </defin>
</Dictionary>
```

Home view code :

---

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Home"
                    creationComplete="srv.send()">

          <fx:Declarations>

                    <s:HTTPService id="srv" url="assets/Dictionary.xml"
                    result="data=srv.lastResult.list.Dictionary"/>                                         
          </fx:Declarations>
          <s:titleContent>
                    <s:TextInput id="key" width="100%"/>
          </s:titleContent>

          <s:actionContent>
                    <s:Button icon="@Embed('assets/search.png')" click="srv.send()"/>
          </s:actionContent>
          <s:List id="list" top="0" bottom="0" left="0" right="0"
                              dataProvider="{srv.lastResult.list.Dictionary}"
                              labelField="term"
                              change="navigator.pushView(Details, list.selectedItem)">
          </s:List>
</s:View>
```

---

Detailview :

---

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                    title=" {data.term}">
          <fx:Declarations>
                    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here         -->
          </fx:Declarations>
          <s:actionContent>
                    <s:Button label="BACK" click="navigator.popToFirstView()"/>
          </s:actionContent>
          <s:TextAreatext="{data.defin}"  />
</s:View>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First, you are waiting for twice the result (with the data binding in the list, plus the result event). Remove the result event. And don't forget to close your XML file with a  tag.

```
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="HomeView">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    <s:HTTPService id="srv" url="myData.xml"/>
</fx:Declarations>
<s:titleContent>
    <s:TextInput id="key" width="100%"/>
</s:titleContent>

<s:actionContent>
    <s:Button  label="search" click="srv.send()"/>
</s:actionContent>
<s:List id="list" top="0" bottom="0" left="0" right="0"
        dataProvider="{srv.lastResult.list.Dictionary}"
        labelField="term"
        change="navigator.pushView(Details, list.selectedItem)">
</s:List>

</s:View>
```

And a Details view that works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Details">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:actionContent>
    <s:Button label="BACK" click="navigator.popToFirstView()"/>
</s:actionContent>
<s:TextArea text="{data.defin}"/>
</s:View>
```

Comment: my issue here is how to make the search button to auto complete search like web pages ... thanks in advance;)